# Android : Read Facebook wall messages (public)

Tags: android, api, graph

Hi please tell me the way to read facebook wall messages(public) in android. I know we can establish http connection to the graph url of facebook and get json string from that.After  parsing json we can get the wall messages.

But my problem is, what is the graph url?

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/ID/feed?access_token=token

Where ID is the id of the page in question and of course token is the users access token

Comment: Hi can u please tell me what is the "users access token"

Comment: [I think this link should explain it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589748/is-there-any-way-i-can-get-public-feed-of-some-user-or-application-without-loggin/6589908#6589908) - view the 'accepted' answer